# why use of deleted rvalue reference constructor function?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a very simple example with class A and B.
I want allow only deep copy, so I disabled the rvalue reference constructor.

```
#include <iostream>

class B;

class A {
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    A(const A & other);
    A& operator=(const A & other);
    A(A && ) = delete;
    A& operator=(A && ) = delete;
    B toB() const;

private:
    int a_;
};

class B {
public:
    B();
    ~B();
    B(const B & other);
    B& operator=(const B & other);
    B(B && ) = delete;
    B& operator=(B && ) = delete;
    A toA() const;

private:
    int b_;
};

A::A()
{
}

A::~A()
{
}
A::A(const A & other)
        : a_(other.a_)
{
}
A& A::operator=(const A & other)
{
    a_ = other.a_;
    return *this;
}

B A::toB() const
{
    return B();
}

B::B()
{
}
B::~B()
{
}
B::B(const B & other)
        : b_(other.b_)
{
}
B& B::operator=(const B & other)
{
    b_ = other.b_;
    return *this;
}

A B::toA() const
{
    return A();
}


int main()
{
    A a();
    B b();

    return 0;
}
```

the gcc compiler report bugs like this:

```
In member function 'B A::toB() const':
error: use of deleted function 'B::B(B&&)'
     return B();
              ^
note: declared here
     B(B && ) = delete;
```

I'm wandering why it use `B(B && )` function, not the `B(const B &)` function instead.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the default copy constructor would work fine in this case, no need to implement your own which does the exact same thing as the default copy constructor. Same with the copy assignment operator. You can actually remove all non-default constructors and all assignment operators, and the code will work just fine. Keep the default constructor but change it to actually initialize the member variables.

Comment: As a follow-up to my previous comment, always go with [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) first and foremost.

Comment: note that `A a();` and `B b();` are useless function declarations, maybe you meant `A a; B b;`

Comment: @M.M yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move Constructor would be called whenever a nameless object is created.

In `B A::toB() const` function there is a statement `return B();` which creates a nameless object to be returned from the function. For creating a nameless object move constructor is required which is deleted.

Comment: What you call "nameless object" is usually called *temporary* object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude true, although IMO "nameless object" is a good description; sometimes temporary objects can last the lifetime of the program!

Answer (score 4):

Because you *added* the move-constructor. Deleted but declared functions are still part of the interface of a class. That means it will be considered by the compiler, but since it's marked as deleted you get the error. If you want to force the copy-constructor to be called then remove the move-constructor declaration.

---

From [this deleted functions reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions):

> Any use of a deleted function is ill-formed (the program will not compile). This includes calls, both explicit (with a function call operator) and implicit (a call to deleted overloaded operator, **special member function**, ...

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

Since the deleted functions are part of the interface, the compiler will try to use them. So when there is a deleted move constructor, the compiler will see that and try to use it, but since it is deleted there will be an error.

Since no move constructor will be created by the compiler if there is an explicit copy constructor (as per [this move constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)) simply having a defaulted copy constructor will inhibit moving of object.

All of that means your classes can be very much simplified:

```
class A {
public:
    A() : a_() {}

    A(const A & other) = default;

    B toB() const;

private:
    int a_;
};

class B {
public:
    B() : b_() {}

    B(const B & other) = default;

    A toA() const;

private:
    int b_;
};
```

Because the classes above have user-declared copy constructors no movement constructor will be created, and the class can't be moved only copied.

Comment: just remove it ?

Comment: I think I have some misunderstanding about copy-constructor and move-constructor, are they exclusive from each other ?

Comment: I mean, when I declare the copy-constructor for class A, is it a must not declare the move-constructor, and the same for a turn between them ?

Comment: @zhaochenyou They are independent, both can be present, none can be present or just one of them can be present.

Comment: Have one doubt: If move c'tor in not specifically added/deleted then will it not call the move c'tor when a nameless object is created? That's what OP want's to avoid.

Comment: @sameerkn If you see e.g. [this move constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) you can see that the compiler will not create a move constructor if there is a user-specified copy constructor (even if it is marked as `default` or `delete`).

Comment: @zhaochenyou If you only want to make the class copyable but not moveable, then it's enough with the copy constructor. If you have a user-defined copy constructor (like you do) then the compiler will not create a move constructor.

Comment: [1] I agree on, if only copy c'tor is explicitly defined then move c'tor won't be implicitly generated. [2] Also in reference its specified that "If the implicitly-declared move constructor is neither deleted...then it will used while copy generation". But cannot find something which states that if the move c'tor is explicitly deleted (as done by OP) then still its part of class. Then, what the use of specifying it as deleted if its still present and is gets used when an object is required to be created from temporary nameless objects?

Comment: +1. "If the function is overloaded, overload resolution takes place first, and the program is only ill-formed if the deleted function was selected."  Why it does not selects the **next** applicable function in overload resolution process?

Comment: @sameerkn Because the compiler *found* a suitable function. It doesn't need, and should not look any further. That the function is deleted is irrelevant for that (otherwise what would be the use of deleted functions if the compiler can just ignore them).